# Python script to Upload Image on Image Hosting sites and get uploaded image Url

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried writing python code to upload file on Image Hosting sites (like postimages.org) and i'm able to do it with below script:

import requests

web_url = 'https://postimages.org/'

files = {'file': open('image.png', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(web_url, files=files)

print(r.status_code) # output: 200

**but how can I get uploaded image Url?**
here, r.text doesn't give me this information.

Comment: Indent code for clarity

Comment: Because you are uploading the files to the home page which just ignores it, you need to upload your files to https://postimages.org/json/rr